# Cloud vs NoSQL for scalable web applications

Tags: azure, cassandra, cloud, scalability, nosql

I want to have some basic understanding of the following.
In order to build a scalable web application, what are the options they have ?

What is the difference among the following
1) simply using noSQL databases(like Cassandra)  for scalability
2) Using cloud services (like Azure, Openstack) for scalability
3) Using noSQL databases on top of cloud platforms for scalability

Which method is extremely scalable ?
Which among these are generally preferred by organizations these days

Please explain in a simple manner since I am new to these.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A database like cassandra gives you scalability at the database layer, but still doesn't address the application layer - you can have a thousand cassandra nodes in a cluster, serving millions of writes per second, but to support that amount of traffic, you'll also need dozens or hundreds of application servers actually talking to the clients.

That's where technologies like AWS / Azure / Openstack come into play - giving you the ability to create new webservers/application servers quickly and easily (and in the case of AWS and Azure, on leased hardware so you're not paying for the physical machines, datacenter space, and dedicated bandwidth, you're only paying for what you use).

It's common for people to combine NoSQL dbs like Cassandra on top of clouds like AWS/Azure, because they can spin up more systems as demand grows without having to do capital expenditures (buying servers), and they can turn nodes off as demand shrinks (for example, if you're running an ad during the superbowl, you can turn on 1000 machines on Saturday, run the superbowl ad, serve the resulting traffic, and then turn off 800 of the machines when you no longer need them on Tuesday).

Comment: Thanks a lot for the detailed explanation. I understood the logic. But how about scaling up web applications just by scaling up cloud architecture (without scaling up databases) ? As far as I have understood from your explanation, We can't scale up just the cloud architecture alone because database will be a bottleneck and similarly vice versa. Am I right ?